# How to make Gazebo use CUDA?

Tags: ros, gazebo, cuda

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A few things I've read so far:

- http://www.ros.org/wiki/diamondback#physics_ode_1.4
- http://www.ros.org/wiki/parallel_quickstep

So, with diamondback, assuming I have all the correct NVIDIA drivers and CUDA toolkit installed and working, does Gazebo automatically use CUDA? If not, then where are the files that the parallel_quickstep instructions point to? Namely, "Makefile.gazebo.cuda" and "cuda.patch"? They're not in my gazebo directory by default after a diamondback install.

Thanks,
Sean

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9781/how-to-make-gazebo-use-cuda?/) by [seanarm](https://answers.ros.org/users/443/seanarm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 753 on 2011-04-20

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

The [instructions on the wiki](http://ros.org/wiki/parallel_quickstep) has been updated, please take a look and let me know if it makes any sense.

Thanks,

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2011-04-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ben](https://answers.ros.org/users/33/ben/) on 2011-04-26**:
What kind of speedup can be expected by using Cuda?